# Use multiple lists as input arguments of a function (Python)

Tags: python, function, input, multiple-arguments

I know that the property map(function,list) applies a function to each element of a single list. But how would it be if my function requires more than one list as input arguments?.

For example I tried:

```
   def testing(a,b,c):
      result1=a+b
      result2=a+c
      return (result1,result2)

a=[1,2,3,4]
b=[1,1,1,1]
c=[2,2,2,2]

result1,result2=testing(a,b,c)
```

But this only concatenates the arrays:

```
result1=[1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1]
result2=[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

and what I need is the following result:

```
result1=[2,3,4,5] 
result2=[3,4,5,6]
```

I would be grateful if somebody could let me know how would this be possible or point me to a link where my question could be answered in a similar case.

Comment: If you want to do mathematical operations on vectors, use a library such as `numpy`, especially if you are going to do this often.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `operator.add`

```
from operator import add

def testing(a,b,c):
    result1 = map(add, a, b)
    result2 = map(add, b, c)
    return (result1, result2)
```

Comment: Be careful, on python 3.x `map` returns a generator not a list.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `zip`:

```
def testing(a,b,c):
    result1=[x + y for x, y in zip(a, b)]
    result2=[x + y for x, y in zip(a, c)]
    return (result1,result2)

a=[1,2,3,4]
b=[1,1,1,1]
c=[2,2,2,2]

result1,result2=testing(a,b,c)
print result1 #[2, 3, 4, 5]
print result2 #[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick and simple:

```
result1 = [a[i] + b[i] for i in range(0,len(a))]
result2 = [a[i] + c[i] for i in range(0,len(a))]
```

(Or for safety you can use `range(0, min(len(a), len(b))`)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of list, use array from numpy instead. 
list concatenate while arrays add corresponding elements. Here I converted the input to numpy arrays. You can feed the function numpy arrays and avoid the conversion steps.

```
def testing(a,b,c):
    a = np.array(a)
    b = np.array(b)
    c = np.array(c)
    result1=a+b
    result2=a+c
    return (result1,result2)

a=[1,2,3,4]
b=[1,1,1,1]
c=[2,2,2,2]

result1,result2=testing(a,b,c)
```

print(result1, result2)